# RegEx - Match first group of four digits .. unless

Tags: regex

I have a collection of strings that I need to extract a group of numbers from. In the pattern below I am trying to select the value at `zzzz`.

```
xxxx - yyyy - aaaa - zzzz - any text here - any text here <= Example #1

xxxx - yyyy - zzzz - any text here - any text here <= Example #2
```

I know the following about the data:

1. xxx will always be three digits
2. yyyy could be digits or alpha characters
3. zzzz will always consist of exactly four digits
4. aaaa could be any sequence of characters but may also be missing altogether as seen in Example #2

I had originally thought I could use Negative Lookahead as in the regex `(?!1111)\d{4}` because the sequence `1111` usually came before my four digit number I wanted to capture.

432 - 1111 - **2300** - Store

411 - 1111 - **6483** - School

However that is not always the case as in the following.

321 - StorageZone - **1710** - Warehouse

In addition sometimes `1111` was in the position I wanted to capture.

002 - 1111 - **1111** - Machine Room (Here I want to select 111 because it is the second instance of 1111)

981 - 0110 - **1111** - Basement (Here 1111 is the number I need)

So I am perplexed on how to capture the value of `zzzz` and could use some regex advice. Thanks.

Comment: Can `any text` be 4-digit number?

Comment: @PM - No ... it will never be four digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript notation it will be something like this:

```
^\d{3} - [a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}?( - .*?)?? - (\d{4})( - [^0-9]*){1,2}$
```

and you will need the 2nd capturing group

The idea here that you need the **last** 4-digit number in the string.

You can test it with this [**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/19a398/1)